# Route some traffic to VM that is connected to a VPN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, proxy

**Problem**

I need to connect to a corporate VPN using a client software that only runs on Windows. I am on MacOS. I would like to set up a Virtual Machine that runs Windows 10 with the VPN software. I want some traffic (requests to corporate's internal network) to be routed from the host machine to the VM (which is connected to the VPN). All other traffic should go straight to the internet without any re-routing.

The traffic to be routed: Browsing websites (HTTP(S)) and using git (over SSH).

**Idea**

My idea was to have an automatic proxy configuration (PAC file) in MacOS's system preferences that sends some traffic to the VM. The VM runs a Squid proxy on port 3128.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    PROXY = "PROXY 192.168.0.140:3128"

    if (shExpMatch(host,"*.corporate.internal")) {
        return PROXY;
    }
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

My approach could be completely off because I do know next to nothing about networking—or maybe it just needs some configuration. Either way it's currently not working.

Any input on how to solve the problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly is the traffic characterized that you wish to route through the VM?

Comment: @jvda Browsing websites over HTTP/S and using git over SSH

Answer (score 0):

With the classification of the traffic you added I would approach this problem as follows. This is a more lower-level (ie based on routing) solution compared to yours which uses a web proxy inside the VM. The advantage of doing it on that level is that you can target other application layer protocols than HTTP (e.g. SSH as wanted by you). Additionally, this would be a system-wide configuration that removes the necessity to install the proxy into each application manually.

1. Ensure the windows VM [forwards packets](https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows)
2. Ensure the windows VM uses its virtual interface for all packets by checking the [routing table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008).
3. Create a routing table on your macOS machine pointing to the VM as the next hop
4. Create a routing policy on your macOS machine that will target the traffic you described (e.g. combining port and destination addresses) and use table from (3) to route these packets

Step 3 might have to be dynamically switched on or off depending on presence of the VM.

> (..) because I do know next to nothing about networking

What the steps above achieve is, very roughly said, the following:

1. Turns the VM into a router.
2. Tells the VM router to use the VPN as outgoing interface for all packets
3. This is just a static route telling the macOS host for which destinations to forward packets to the VM.
4. Normally, routers simply use destination addresses/prefix to decide the outgoing interface and next hop. A routing policy allows to use different information to make that decision. This is required in your case since you only want to target specific application-layer protocols, hence the necessity to peak above the network-layer.

Edit 1: For step 1 to work, you will probably also have to setup networking of the VM in a "bridge mode", so that it is addressable on the host OS.