# Routing traffic through windows VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, routing

I have a windows VM running on KVM and connected through a NAT network to my guest.
I cannot use anything else than a NAT network because the windows VM has a corporate software that allows only one connection.
The guest windows VM runs a custom VPN that can only run on windows.
My host machine is running Linux and I would like to redirect some of the traffic through the VM and the VPN (e.g 10.0.0.0/8).

What I'm trying to do:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│            Windows VM               │
│      ┌────────────────────────┐     │
│      │                        │     │                ┌───────────────────────┐
│      │                    ┌───▼─────┤                │                       │
│      │ 192.168.122.2      │   VPN   │     ┌─────┐    │   Corporate network   │
├──────┼────────────────────┴───┬─────┤     │     │    │                       │
│      │       NAT network      └─────┼────►│ WWW ├───►│  10.0.0.0/8           │
│      │                              │     │     │    │                       │
├──────┼──────────────────────────────┤     └─────┘    │                       │
│      │ 192.168.122.1                │                └───────────────────────┘
│                                     │
│                                     │
│            Linux guest              │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

What I have tried:

- Enabled ip forwarding on the guest VM
- Add a route on the host to the guest machine (ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.122.2)

But traceroute shows me that the VM does not forward the requests.

Is it possible to do this with NAT networking ? How would you do that ?

I have seen other questions on the topic ([Route some traffic to VM that is connected to a VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1645705/route-some-traffic-to-vm-that-is-connected-to-a-vpn)) but could not find a way to implement the correct routing.

Answer (score 0):

It would work in theory but not necessarily in practice, as corporate VPN clients may deliberately prevent packets from outside from being forwarded even if everything is set up correctly. (For example, Cisco's AnyConnect is one such client, from what I've heard.)

Using "NAT networking" should not be a problem, as typically the "NAT" part of it only applies to packets leaving the host completely, while between the host and guests it's just a bridged Ethernet subnet. (If there's no gateway between two hosts, there's no NAT either.)

However, you actually need NAT at a different place – in addition to the routes that you've added, you also need the Windows machine to masquerade all packets coming from the host before they get forwarded to the VPN interface. Without SNAT here, the VPN server (and your corp network) will see packets originating from your LAN IP address – they might be filtered by the VPN client, they might be rejected at the VPN server, and even if they aren't rejected, devices in the corp network will have no idea how to *reply* to them.

So in situations where you have no control over the remote network (i.e. you're not setting up a proper site-to-site VPN), the "VPN client" machine needs to SNAT all packets from 192.168.122.x as if they were coming from the "VPN client" itself (from its 10.something address).

I don't know how to enable SNAT/masquerade in Windows 10, although I'm sure the functionality is there because Hyper-V enables it on the default vSwitch on consumer editions (so you could probably install Hyper-V within the Windows VM and make the "physical" Ethernet interface a member of the vSwitch?)